# bread-and-butter vs. bread and butter

Tags: grammar

My English teacher said that "bread-and-butter" was a slice of bread spread with butter and "bread and butter" was just bread and butter literally and the pronunciation of the former was interlinked but the pronunciation of the latter was not interlinked. After the class I lookd up the words in a dictionary. the meanings in a dictionary was so different with them he taught me and the pronunciations all were interlinked like breadeun butter.

And he let me translate a sentence(situation : A man was walking on the street and I was in his way) into English so I wrote like this "He asked me to move out of his way" and then he removed "of his way" without any explanation. 
I have known that "move out" is moving to a strange place. 
Is it possible to write "move out", or to use "out" for emphasis in that case?

Thank you for reading through :)

Comment: You have two questions in one.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your teacher's views on the difference that dashes (hyphens) make in this instance are unique to himself.

Dictionary references make it clear that the expression *bread and butter*, with or without hyphens, is used mainly as a metaphor for basic issues or matters, especially earning a living. When it refers to food, it is used without hyphens but the meaning is identical either way.

Regarding *the man walking on the street*, there are three possibilities.

> He could ask you to move

which signifies a request to move aside in order to let him pass.

> He could ask you to move out of his way

which is another way of saying exactly the same thing but being a little more specific.

> He could ask you to move out.....

but the expression **move out** does NOT apply in this context. It's an expression meaning to leave one's lodgings, generally used by landlords. It's also much used in the movies when officers call on their troops to get going. So your teacher is wrong to use it here.

In this context, the choice is between examples 1 and 2. The only virtue that *to move* has over *to move out of his way* is that of brevity.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bread-and-butter

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bread-and-butter

Comment: reading your answer, I find the move out of his way and move out confusingly explained at first.....But I do agree with your move/move out of his way.

Answer (score 1):

Please ask one question per post, to avoid confusion.

For your "bread-and-butter" question: In English, this would be "bread and butter" regardless of whether it was spread or not. It can also be used colloquially to mean someone's primary skill area or regular source of income. "Cleaning watches was his bread and butter."

The only time you should see those linked with hyphens is when the phrase is used as an adjective to something else. In English, multi-word adjectives are hyphenated to distinguish them from multiple adjectives.

"Small-town thinking comes from living in a small town." In the first occurrence, "small-town" is an adjective describing the thinking. It's not "small" thinking or "town" thinking. It's thinking that is characteristic of living in a "small town", thus "small-town" thinking. In the latter occurrence, it is the standard noun phrase "small town" so it is not hyphenated.

With thanks to the examples from the comments: "The politician focused on bread-and-butter issues." vs. "These issues were her bread and butter."

Comment: bread-and-butter sandwich; bread-and-butter issues as adjectives.  You are welcome to them and then I will delete this.

Comment: An example: "The politician focused on bread-and-butter issues".